# Can't style the ActionBar Dropdown Navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have my own style theme in my application. I'm trying to change the default color scheme of the Drop Down Navigation. I added these lines:

```
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
```

and

```
<style name="MyDropDownNav">
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/vermelho</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/seletor2</item>
</style>
```

But the default styling in list navigation mode has a blue colour scheme. Nothing changed.

The full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Tema" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>


        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/seletor2</item>
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/laranja</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/verdeapp</item> // cor dos itens
    </style>
    <style name="PopupMenu.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">                          @drawable/popup_menu_bg_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.titleTextStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.titleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/branco</item>  // cor do título
    </style>

    <!-- style the list navigation -->
    <style name="MyDropDownNav">
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/vermelho</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/seletor2</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override next field in your appTheme:

```
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupMenuListView</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/AppTheme.Text.SingleLine.Common</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/AppTheme.Text.SingleLine.Common</item>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenuListView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/pressed_state_background</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps You.

Comment: I am not using appCombat

Comment: Override in <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
    </style> ?

Comment: All elements exists in Holo theme. Override them using Holo widgets as parents